# Emoluments case

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, us-president

It's my understanding that the Trump Administration is or was facing two emoluments related cases.
The first regarded a hotel and the [case was dismissed](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/07/10/trump-wins-dismissal-of-emoluments-suit.html).

The second was brought by 198 members of Congress and I can't find out any current information about it. The last thing I read was in [April 2019](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-court-emoluments/democrats-suit-against-trump-over-foreign-payment-can-proceed-judge-idUSKCN1S72YL).

What's the current situation with regard to this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this CNBC story](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/02/07/trump-wins-appeal-of-emoluments-clause-lawsuit-by-democrats.html) the case brought by members of Congress (*Blumenthal v. Trump*) was dismissed for lack of standing by a three-judge panel at the Circuit Court level. As [reported earlier](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/05/01/judge-democrats-suit-against-trump-over-foreign-payment-can-proceed.html) a federal district court judge had allowed the case to proceed.

[This 2017 Politico story](https://www.politico.com/story/2017/12/21/judge-dismisses-suits-emoluments-312610) reported on the dismissal of an earlier suit on the same issue, also for lack of standing.

The AP story ["Supreme Court ends Trump emoluments lawsuits"](https://apnews.com/article/supreme-court-ends-trump-lawsuits-df42ef0eec5fa57edf3e294234051d88) reports that in Jan 2021 the US Supreme Court dismissed remaining cases on the issue as moot, since Trump was no longer President.

In the piece ["Supreme Court Ducks an Opportunity on Trump Emoluments Cases"](https://www.brennancenter.org/our-work/analysis-opinion/supreme-court-ducks-opportunity-trump-emoluments-cases) by  Ciara Torres-Spelliscy  of the Brennan Center, the author reviewed the history of the constitutional provisions, expressed the view that rump had violated them, and suggested that new legislation should be passed to deal with any future cases of a similar sort.  So far as I know, no such legislation has been introduced to date.